# How to loop over a nested list to number each list from 1 to 5:

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

So i'm making a game for an assignment and i need make a function that takes in a nested list representing the game board and numbers each row from 1 to 5 (for co-ordinates eg F4, G3 and so on).

Say for example the list representing the board looks like this:

```
board = [['S', 'S', 'X', 'S', 'S'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', 'T', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['S', 'S', 'Y', 'S', 'S']]
```

I need to add a number to the first position for each list so i get something that looks like this:

```
board = [[1, 'S', 'S', 'X', 'S', 'S'],
         [2, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         [3, '.', '.', 'T', '.', '.'],
         [4, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         [5, 'S', 'S', 'Y', 'S', 'S']]
```

and displays it like so:

```
1 S S X S S
2 . . . . .
3 . . T . .
4 . . . . .
5 S S Y S S
```

My current method of doing this is like this:

```
def display_board(board):
     bottomLetters  = [" ", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"]
     print board
     counter = int(0)
     for row in board:
         counter += int(1)
         row.insert(0, counter)
         for positon in row:
             print positon,
             print
```

This nearly works but i get a weird output:

```
1 S S X S S
2 . . . . .
3 . . T . .
4 2 . . . . .
5 S S Y S S
```

or just the gameboard list itself:

```
board = [[1, 'S', 'S', 'X', 'S', 'S'],
         [4, 2, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         [3, '.', '.', 'T', '.', '.'],
         [4, 2, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         [5, 'S', 'S', 'Y', 'S', 'S']]
```

Anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try the code you gave us ? Because it's working as you expect. Must be somewhere else in your code

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer - but a bit of advice.

You don't need `int(0)` you can just use `0`. Also, Python already provides a builtin method to "number" items in a sequence called `enumerate`. Also look at the `str.join` method to make formatting text easier for printing.

Using the above you can reduce your code to:

```
board = [['S', 'S', 'X', 'S', 'S'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', 'T', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['S', 'S', 'Y', 'S', 'S']]

def display_board(board):
    for rowno, items in enumerate(board, start=1):
        print rowno, ' '.join(items)

display_board(board)
```

This is not only more Pythonic but clearer as to your intent.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to replicate your results, but the issue that stands out here is that you're modifying the board (prepending the counter) each time your run `display_board()`. Any code that expect your board to be of the original format will break once you've displayed it.

Here's how I would approach it:

```
def display_board(board):
  for counter, row in enumerate(board, start=1):
    print counter, " ".join(row)
  print " ".join(" ABCDEFGHIJK"[:len(board[0])+1])
```

Sample output:

```
>>> display_board(board)
1 S S X S S
2 . . . . .
3 . . T . .
4 . . . . .
5 S S Y S S
  A B C D E
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting this bug is that the board you are showing us is not actually as you define it... am I correct?

Note how the second and the fourth row look the same. In your data structure they end up being *exactly the same object*, that's why modifying row number two affects also row number four.

Are you by any means initializing the rows individually, and then assigning them to the board, repeating the second row? In that case, be aware that you are not *copying* them but actually storing references to the same object.

Comment: Thanks, i've spent hours trying to figure out why it was doing that and this makes much more sense than anything i've come up with

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't change the data structure just to save some effort displaying it and break the logic at the same time. Numbers are not a part of the board and shouldn't be mixed with game figures. I would do something like:

```
In [1]: %paste
board = [['S', 'S', 'X', 'S', 'S'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', 'T', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['S', 'S', 'Y', 'S', 'S']]
## -- End pasted text --

In [2]: from string import ascii_uppercase

In [3]: def display(b):
    for i, row in enumerate(b, 1):
        print i, ' '.join(row)
    print ' ', ' '.join(x for _, x in zip(row, ascii_uppercase))

In [4]: display(board)
1 S S X S S
2 . . . . .
3 . . T . .
4 . . . . .
5 S S Y S S
  A B C D E
```